# Laravel Passport & nuxt.js & nginx - oAuth not working

Tags: laravel, nginx, oauth, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I'm running a static built nuxt.js app on my server. It uses the [nuxt auth module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module) for authentificating against my laravel backend which runs [laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport).

My auth-strategy looks like this:

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravel.passport': {
        url: 'https://correct_url',
        //client_id: 1, //for local use
        //client_secret: 'CLIENTSECRET1', //for local use
        client_id: 2,
        client_secret: 'CLIENTSECRET2',
        userinfo_endpoint: 'https://correct_url/oauth/me'
      }
    }
  },
```

In my local environment (`yarn run dev`) everything runs fine. After I built and deployed my nuxt-app (`yarn run build`) the authentification process comes to the authorisation step (where I can click "Authorize" or "cancel"). After I click "Authorize" browser redirects to my nuxt-app but requests still give me:

`{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`

After a few investigations the only possible cause for this could be the nginx-site which is automatically created through laravel forge. Config looks like this:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/correct_url/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name correct_url;
    root /home/forge/correct_url/dist;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/correct_url/589448/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/correct_url/589448/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/correct_url/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/correct_url-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/correct_url/after/*;
```

is there something I overlooked or am I on the wrong path?

Comment: Did you fix your issue ? If yes, how ?